# Add FacebookConnect to cordova in netbeans

Tags: android, facebook, apache, netbeans, cordova

I'm using cordova with the latest Netbeans build 7.4, which has the cordova integration included.

I added the following line to `nbproject/plugins.propteries` and can clearly see, that the plugin is fetched:

> Calling plugman.fetch on plugin
>   "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git" Fetching
>   plugin "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git" via
>   git clone

After that, the build crashes, due to missing info:

> Error: Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME

Where can I add the missing info, which is the correct file and syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good tutorial [here](http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/01/facebook-login-logout-using-cordova-330.html), which has solved my problem.